# How to populate ember-cli-jstree with model data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, jstree

I am trying to use this addon to create a tree from my data. I can successfully create a tree from the examples provided in the [test/dummy](https://github.com/ritesh83/ember-cli-jstree/tree/7521d2b88625597b1d8339482981918d1e6c6e0a/tests/dummy) in github, but when I try to use data from a model it seems to be expecting json data and not the ember model.

```
// models/user.js 
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  children: DS.hasMany('user', {inverse: 'parent', async: true}),
  parent: DS.belongsTo('user', {inverse: 'children', async: true})
});

// routes/users.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('user');
  }
});

// templates/users.hbs    
<h2>Users</h2>
<div class="sample-tree">
   {{ember-jstree
      data= model
   }}
</div>
```

I have searched for a working example but so far have not found one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it expects a plain old JavaScript object in a particular format, not an Ember Data model.

There is an open source working example in Ember Twiddle here: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-twiddle/blob/7e6739a5fb4c80c454bd173ca93ecbb4f1777250/app/components/file-tree.js#L12

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav. So the functionality of having an integrated data model needs to be implemented manually? Adding, deleting and updating records? I can use users.map(function(user) { return user.toJSON({ includeId: true });} to get the pojo but then I lose the data model.

Comment: Yes, but notice that I use a computed property to recalculate the tree's data every time the model changes. Also notice that you have to actually ids for every node, and some "parent" nodes likely don't even exist in your model. ember-cli-jstree is nothing more than a thin wrapper over the original jquery plugin, and you need to look there for documentation of what you need to provide to jstree.